# NullPointerException Logcat Error Android

Tags: java, android, eclipse, sqlite, nullpointerexception

**LogCat NPE Error**

```
    02-03 16:19:48.172: D/AndroidRuntime(959): Shutting down VM
02-03 16:19:48.182: W/dalvikvm(959): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41465700)
02-03 16:19:48.322: E/AndroidRuntime(959): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-03 16:19:48.322: E/AndroidRuntime(959): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
02-03 16:19:48.322: E/AndroidRuntime(959):  at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3633)
02-03 16:19:48.322: E/AndroidRuntime(959):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4240)
02-03 16:19:48.322: E/AndroidRuntime(959):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17721)
02-03 16:19:48.322: E/AndroidRuntime(959):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
02-03 16:19:48.322: E/AndroidRuntime(959):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
02-03 16:19:48.322: E/AndroidRuntime(959):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-03 16:19:48.322: E/AndroidRuntime(959):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
02-03 16:19:48.322: E/AndroidRuntime(959):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-03 16:19:48.322: E/AndroidRuntime(959):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
02-03 16:19:48.322: E/AndroidRuntime(959):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
02-03 16:19:48.322: E/AndroidRuntime(959):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
02-03 16:19:48.322: E/AndroidRuntime(959):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-03 16:19:48.322: E/AndroidRuntime(959): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
02-03 16:19:48.322: E/AndroidRuntime(959):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-03 16:19:48.322: E/AndroidRuntime(959):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
02-03 16:19:48.322: E/AndroidRuntime(959):  at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3628)
02-03 16:19:48.322: E/AndroidRuntime(959):  ... 11 more
02-03 16:19:48.322: E/AndroidRuntime(959): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-03 16:19:48.322: E/AndroidRuntime(959):  at com.example.universitybudgetub.MainMenu.populateListViewFromDB(MainMenu.java:184)
02-03 16:19:48.322: E/AndroidRuntime(959):  at com.example.universitybudgetub.MainMenu.addRecord(MainMenu.java:135)
02-03 16:19:48.322: E/AndroidRuntime(959):  ... 14 more
```

This is the error message I receive, i cannot seem to to find where the NPE error is in my code. I will provide both MainMenu.java and DBAdpater.java below.

**MainMenu.java**

```
package com.example.universitybudgetub;

import java.io.File;

import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v4.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class MainMenu extends FragmentActivity{

    DBAdapter db = new DBAdapter(this); //Initiate DB class methods
    SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;
    ViewPager mViewPager;


    //OnCreate
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main_menu);
        mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);
    }

    public void onClick(View v){
            String destPath = "/data/data/" + getPackageName() + "/databases/ExpensesDB";
            @SuppressWarnings("unused")
            File f = new File(destPath);
    }

    //OnCreateOptionsMenu 
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);
        return true;
    }

    //SectionsPagerAdapter Controls which Fragment is retrieved for each page
    public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            Fragment fragment;
            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    fragment = new Fragment1();
                    break;
                case 1:
                    fragment = new Fragment2();
                    break;
                case 2:
                    fragment = new Fragment3();
                    break;
                case 3:
                    fragment = new Fragment4();
                    break;
                case 4:
                    fragment = new Fragment5();
                    break;
                default:
                    fragment  = null;
                    break;
            }
            return fragment;
        }

        //Returns the amount of pages to display
        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // Show 3 total pages.
            return 5;
        }

        //Page Title
        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return getString(R.string.title_section1);
            case 1:
                return getString(R.string.title_section2);
            case 2:
                return getString(R.string.title_section3);
            case 3:
                return getString(R.string.title_section4);
            case 4:
                return getString(R.string.title_section5);
            }
            return null;
        }
    }

    //Add New Record
    public void addRecord (View v){

        //Get data from form
        EditText foodTxt = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText_food);
        EditText taxiTxt = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText_taxi);
        EditText clothesTxt = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText_clothes);
        EditText sportsTxt = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText_sports);
        EditText supermarketTxt = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText_supermarket);
        EditText clubs_barsTxt = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText_clubs);
        EditText owed_moneyTxt = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText_owed_money);
        EditText otherTxt = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText_other);
        EditText electric_gasTxt = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText_electric_gas);
        EditText waterbillTxt = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText_water);
        EditText houseTxt = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText_house);
        EditText rentTxt = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText_rent);
        EditText internetTxt = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText_internet);

        db.open();
        @SuppressWarnings("unused")
        long id = db.insertRecord(foodTxt.getText().toString(), clothesTxt.getText().toString(), 
                supermarketTxt.getText().toString(), taxiTxt.getText().toString(), sportsTxt.getText().toString(), 
                clubs_barsTxt.getText().toString(), owed_moneyTxt.getText().toString(), otherTxt.getText().toString(), 
                electric_gasTxt.getText().toString(), waterbillTxt.getText().toString(), rentTxt.getText().toString(),
                houseTxt.getText().toString(), internetTxt.getText().toString()); 

        populateListViewFromDB(); //Re-populate the list after new record is added

        db.close();

        //Set editText fields to empty
        foodTxt.setText("");
        taxiTxt.setText("");
        clothesTxt.setText("");
        sportsTxt.setText("");
        supermarketTxt.setText("");
        clubs_barsTxt.setText("");
        owed_moneyTxt.setText("");
        otherTxt.setText("");
        electric_gasTxt.setText("");
        waterbillTxt.setText("");
        houseTxt.setText("");
        rentTxt.setText("");
        internetTxt.setText("");
        Toast.makeText(MainMenu.this, "Expenses Added", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    private void openDB(){
        db = new DBAdapter(this);
        db.open();
    }

    private void populateListViewFromDB() {
        Cursor cursor = db.getAllRows();

        //Allow activity to manage lifetime of the cursor
        //DEPRECATED!
        startManagingCursor(cursor);

        //Setup mapping from cursor to view fields
        String[] fromFieldNames = new String[] 
                {DBAdapter.KEY_ROWID, DBAdapter.KEY_FOOD, DBAdapter.KEY_CLOTHES, DBAdapter.KEY_SUPERMARKET, DBAdapter.KEY_TAXI, DBAdapter.KEY_SPORTS,
                    DBAdapter.KEY_CLUBS_BARS, DBAdapter.KEY_OWED_MONEY, DBAdapter.KEY_OTHER, DBAdapter.KEY_ELECTRIC_GAS, DBAdapter.KEY_WATERBILL,
                        DBAdapter.KEY_RENT, DBAdapter.KEY_HOUSE, DBAdapter.KEY_INTERNETBILL,};
        int[] toViewIDs = new int[]
                {R.id.textView_itemid, R.id.textView_itemfood, R.id.textView_itemclothes, R.id.textView_itemsupermarket, R.id.textView_itemtaxi, R.id.textView_itemsports,
                    R.id.textView_itemclubs, R.id.textView_itemowed, R.id.textView_itemother, R.id.textView_itemelectric, R.id.textView_itemwater, 
                        R.id.textView_itemrent, R.id.textView_itemhouse, R.id.textView_iteminternet,};

        //Create Adapter to map columns of the DB into elements in the UI
        SimpleCursorAdapter myCursorAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
                this, //Context
                R.layout.history_expenses_layout, //Row layout template
                cursor, //cursor (set of DB REcords to map)
                fromFieldNames, //DB Column names
                toViewIDs // View IDs to put information in
                );

        //Set the adapter for the list view
        ListView myList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewFromDB);
        myList.setAdapter(myCursorAdapter);
    }


}
```

**DBAdapter.java**

```
package com.example.universitybudgetub;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;


public class DBAdapter {
    public static final String KEY_ROWID = "_id";
    public static final String KEY_FOOD = "food";
    public static final String KEY_CLOTHES = "clothes";
    public static final String KEY_SUPERMARKET = "supermarket";
    public static final String KEY_TAXI= "taxi";
    public static final String KEY_SPORTS = "sports";
    public static final String KEY_CLUBS_BARS = "clubs_bars";
    public static final String KEY_OWED_MONEY = "owed_money";
    public static final String KEY_OTHER = "other";
    public static final String KEY_ELECTRIC_GAS = "electric_gas";
    public static final String KEY_WATERBILL = "waterbill";
    public static final String KEY_RENT = "rent";
    public static final String KEY_HOUSE = "house";
    public static final String KEY_INTERNETBILL = "internetbill";
    private static final String TAG = "DBAdapter";

    public static final String[] ALL_KEYS = new String[] {KEY_ROWID, KEY_FOOD, KEY_CLOTHES, KEY_SUPERMARKET, KEY_TAXI, KEY_SPORTS,
    KEY_CLUBS_BARS, KEY_OWED_MONEY, KEY_OTHER, KEY_ELECTRIC_GAS, KEY_WATERBILL, KEY_RENT, KEY_HOUSE, KEY_INTERNETBILL};

    private static String DATABASE_NAME = "ExpensesDB";
    private static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "expenses";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 4;

    private static final String DATABASE_CREATE = 
            "create table if not exists expenses (_id integer primary key autoincrement, " +
    "food VARCHAR, clothes VARCHAR, supermarket VARCHAR, taxi VARCHAR, sports VARCHAR, clubs_bars VARCHAR, owed_money VARCHAR, other VARCHAR, electric_gas VARCHAR, waterbill VARCHAR, rent VARCHAR, house VARCHAR, internetbill VARCHAR);";

private final Context context;

private DatabaseHelper DBHelper;
private SQLiteDatabase db;

public DBAdapter(Context ctx){
    this.context = ctx;
    DBHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context);
}

//Instantiate's all the database methods
public static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    DatabaseHelper(Context context){
        super (context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db){
        try{
            db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override 
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion){
        Log.w(TAG, "Upgrading data from version " + oldVersion + " to " + newVersion + " , which wll destroy all old data");
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS contacts");
        onCreate(db);
    }
}

//Opens database
public DBAdapter open() throws SQLException{
    db = DBHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    return this;
}

//Close database
public void close(){
    DBHelper.close();
}

//Insert record to database
public long insertRecord(String food, String clothes, String supermarket, String taxi, String sports, String clubs_bars, 
        String owed_money, String other, String electric_gas, String waterbill, String rent, String house, String internetbill){
    ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
    initialValues.put(KEY_FOOD, food);
    initialValues.put(KEY_CLOTHES, clothes);
    initialValues.put(KEY_SUPERMARKET, supermarket);
    initialValues.put(KEY_TAXI, taxi);
    initialValues.put(KEY_SPORTS, sports);
    initialValues.put(KEY_CLUBS_BARS, clubs_bars);
    initialValues.put(KEY_OWED_MONEY, owed_money);
    initialValues.put(KEY_OTHER, other);
    initialValues.put(KEY_ELECTRIC_GAS, electric_gas);
    initialValues.put(KEY_WATERBILL, waterbill);
    initialValues.put(KEY_RENT, rent);
    initialValues.put(KEY_HOUSE, house);
    initialValues.put(KEY_INTERNETBILL, internetbill);
    return db.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, initialValues);
}

//Delete particular record
public boolean deleteRecord(long rowId)
{
    return db.delete(DATABASE_TABLE, KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId, null) > 0;
}

//Retrieve particular record
public Cursor getRecord(long rowId) throws SQLException
{
    Cursor mCursor = db.query(true, DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {KEY_ROWID, KEY_FOOD, KEY_CLOTHES, KEY_TAXI, KEY_SPORTS, 
            KEY_CLUBS_BARS, KEY_OWED_MONEY, KEY_OTHER, KEY_ELECTRIC_GAS, KEY_WATERBILL, KEY_RENT, KEY_HOUSE, KEY_INTERNETBILL},
            KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId, null, null, null, null, null);
    if (mCursor != null) {
            mCursor.moveToFirst();
    }
    return mCursor;
}

//Update particular record
public boolean updateRecord(long rowId, int food, int clothes, int taxi, int sports, int clubs_bars, int owed_money, int other,
        int electric_gas, int waterbill, int rent, int house, int internetbill){
    ContentValues args = new ContentValues();
    args.put(KEY_FOOD, food);
    args.put(KEY_CLOTHES, clothes);
    args.put(KEY_TAXI, taxi);
    args.put(KEY_SPORTS, sports);
    args.put(KEY_CLUBS_BARS, clubs_bars);
    args.put(KEY_OWED_MONEY, owed_money);
    args.put(KEY_OTHER, other);
    args.put(KEY_ELECTRIC_GAS, electric_gas);
    args.put(KEY_WATERBILL, waterbill);
    args.put(KEY_RENT, rent);
    args.put(KEY_HOUSE, house);
    args.put(KEY_INTERNETBILL, internetbill);
    return db.update(DATABASE_TABLE, args, KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId, null) > 0;  
}

// Return all data in the database.
public Cursor getAllRows() {
    String where = null;
    Cursor c =  db.query(true, DATABASE_TABLE, ALL_KEYS, 
                        where, null, null, null, null, null);
    if (c != null) {
        c.moveToFirst();
    }
    return c;
}


}
```

I have placed the list view in a java class called fragment5 and named it with the id listViewFromDB. What i'm trying to do is display the DB information in a list on fragment5. I'm not sure whether having fragments will affect the way the MainMenu.java is able to find ListViewFromDB id as this may have caused the NPE.

Any help would be great!

Comment: Seems error is coming from `addRecord`/`populateListViewFromDB`. What I see is you're opening the DB, and trying to do something with it. I see it is initialized, but I don't think you should add `new DBAdapter(this)` outside onCreate. Can you put it inside and try that?

Answer (score 3):

```
private void openDB(){
    db = new DBAdapter(this);
    db.open();
}
```

This method is not getting called so when you are trying to access the `db` instance it is throwing null pointer exception.

Comment: There's (slightly incorrect) member variable initialization: `DBAdapter db = new DBAdapter(this);`

Comment: Did not noticed it my mistake.

Comment: I've completely got rid of the method `openDB` and just called `db.open()` in my `onCreate` as i noticed i already initiate `DBAdapter db = new DBAdapter(this);` at the beginning. 

It's still giving me a NPE

Comment: refer laalto's answer, seems like it fails to fetch the listview from the layout. Make sure you have one list view present with the listViewFromDB. Also make sure you are getting the cursor as not null.

Answer (score 1):

Row 184 seen in the stacktrace is close enough to these lines:

```
ListView myList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewFromDB);
myList.setAdapter(myCursorAdapter);
```

Make sure your layout set in `setContentView()` actually contains a `ListView` with id `listViewFromDB`.

Comment: Am i right to say instead of using `ListView` i should be using `ListFragment`? As my application extends `MainMenu` to `FragmentActivity` and hence why it isnt able to find id `listViewFromDB`

Comment: You can use `ListView` in any activity/fragment. `ListActivity`/`ListFragment` just come prepackaged with a `ListView` and helper methods for using it.

Comment: Hmm then i'm back to square one, its still throwing an NPE even thought i've made sure `listViewFromDB` exists as an id.

Comment: NPEs are generally quite easy to figure out when single-stepping with a debugger.

Comment: I ran it through a debugger and it errors out after reaching `myList.setAdapter(myCursorAdapter)` any ideas why this keeps happening?

Comment: `myList` is null for the reason mentioned in this answer.